# Change top offset margin for SnapPoint JQuery plugin with Fixed menu

Tags: jquery, offset

I am using the SnapPoint plugin from https://github.com/robspangler/jquery-snappoint and it works well. But i have a fixed menu container of 120px on the top so everytime the slide snaps to the top, it gets hidden behind the menu.

On the authors website, he mentioned a while ago that to overcome this issue padding-top: could be used, but my design does not allow using the padding-top solution.

Is there another non-css way to hardcode the offset via JQuery to 120px when it snaps ?

Thanks in advance