# Snap individual divs at 120px offset from top

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have the following site structure. Is there a way to snap the top edge of the div containers below my fixed menu when i scroll ? I tried almost all the snapscrolls out there but none works the way i want it to. Is a CSS method good of this kind of stuff or am i bound to jquery.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="menuContainer">MENU</div>
    <div class="topExtra"></div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color:#5d9732;">ONE</div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color:#00aeef;">TWO</div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color:#c3cf21;">THREE</div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color:#aeb9bf;">FOUR</div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color:#5d9732;">ONE</div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color:#00aeef;">TWO</div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color:#c3cf21;">THREE</div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color:#aeb9bf;">FOUR</div>
</div>

#container { margin:auto; width:500px; overflow:hidden; }
.topExtra { margin:auto; width:500px; height:120px;  }
.menuContainer { margin:auto; position:fixed; width:500px; height:120px; background-color:#aeb9bf;  }
.slide { margin:auto; width:500px; height:200px;  }
```

The slides are not fullscreen or 100% width. I have made a fiddle of the structure. Hoping someone can shed some light please. 
http://jsfiddle.net/yx4p2/3/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change top offset margin for SnapPoint JQuery plugin with Fixed menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749138/change-top-offset-margin-for-snappoint-jquery-plugin-with-fixed-menu)

Comment: Hi cinnamon, its a functional duplicate of the question. The http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749138/change-top-offset-margin-for-snappoint-jquery-plugin-with-fixed-menu concentrates on the SnapPoint plugin itself. I could not get that plugin to work, hence this post where i want this functionality from scratch if possible without external jquery to try and understand how this works. Sorry if i shouldent have reposted the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to act on the `window.onscroll` event and attach a function to it.

*Update: you meant something else.*

It scrolls the menu down when scrolled over it for 2 seconds.

Code:

```
$(function () 
{
    // To keep from scrolling while scrolling
    var scrolling = false;

    window.onscroll = function (e) 
    {
        var timer,
            top    = $(".menuContainer").offset().top,
            bottom = top + $(".menuContainer").outerHeight();

        // Reset when scrolling again before animation
        clearTimeout(timer);

        if (!scrolling && window.pageYOffset > top && window.pageYOffset < bottom) 
        {
            // Set timer to scroll after 2 seconds
            timer = setTimeout(function () 
            {
                scrolling = true;
                if (window.pageYOffset > top && window.pageYOffset < bottom) 
                {
                    // The scrolling
                    $("html").animate({ scrollTop: bottom + "px" }, 100, function () 
                        {
                            // Done, no longer scrolling
                            scrolling = false;
                        });
                }
                else
                    scrolling = false;

            }, 2000);
        }
    }
});
```

Test on jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yx4p2/5/).

Comment: Hi GeenHenk i wanted the individual slides to snap below the fixed menu. Just like so: http://robspangler.com/git/jquery-snappoint/demo/demo.html Can that be possible with jQuery ?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in reply, GeenHenk- your solution is for the first slide to snap to the bottom of the top menu when the mouse is hovered on the menu for 2sec. What i was going for was similar to this option http://benoit.pointet.info/stuff/jquery-scrollsnap-plugin/ . But the only reason i cant use it is because it uses <section> instead of <div>. I wanted all the slides to snap to the bottom of the fixed menu when we scroll through them. Here is another example: http://guidobouman.github.io/jquery-panelsnap/